# QML MediaPlayer H264 not playing but MP4 works

Tags: qt, video, qml, mp4, h.264

I have a h264/264 file and i am trying to play it in QML like this:

```
    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaplayer
        source: "file:///blah.h264"
    }

    VideoOutput{
        id: videoPlayer
        anchors.fill: parent
        source:mediaplayer
    }

    MouseArea {
            id: playArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed:  {
                console.log("play")
                mediaplayer.play()
            }
    }
```

it doesn't work. i tried the same but with a .mp4 file that worked but this doesnt.
Also i am using python pyside if that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Most playback engines don’t support raw streams. Put the file in a container. ffmpeg -i blah.264 -codec copy blah.mp4